# How to format date in a system date format using Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to convert the date into a system date format. For Example,
if the system date format is **DD-MM-YYYY**, then my web application should show **30-11-2021**,
and on another system, if the date format is **MM-DD-YYYY**, then it should show **11-30-2021**.
Basically, it should convert to the date format of the client's system.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

```
function formatDate(d: Date): string {

  let lang: string;
  if (navigator.languages != undefined) {
    lang = navigator.languages[0]; 
  } else {
    lang = navigator.language;
  }

  const options: DateTimeFormatOptions = {
    year: 'numeric',
    month: '2-digit',
    day: '2-digit',
  };

  return new Intl.DateTimeFormat(lang, options).format(d);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution N.F., I tried this but when I change the system date format it is not changing the date format in my web app.